# Vagrant VMs are not detected when using Ansible (local_action) to spin up vagrant

Tags: vagrant, ansible

Consider the following Ansible playbook code...

```
# provisioning/roles/operations/tasks/vagrant.yml
---
- block:
  - name: Copy vagrantfile onto dev machine
    local_action:
      template src=Vagrantfile.j2
      dest={{playbook_dir}}/../Vagrantfile

  - name: Boot up VMs
    local_action:
      command vagrant up
    environment:
      VAGRANT_VAGRANTFILE: "{{playbook_dir}}/../Vagrantfile"
    register: vagrantUpResults

  - debug: msg="{{vagrantUpResults}}"

  tags:
  - vagrant
```

This will correctly generate a valid `Vagrantfile` and will successfully run the "vagrant up" command.  However, by doing this through ansible it seems it will not register the created newly created VMs.  I know this because when I run...

```
vagrant status
```

I see lines that declare "VM (not started)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the correct ".vagrant" directory was being generated in ./provisioning whereas the Vagrantfile was generated to ./Vagrantfile.  Although "VAGRANT_VAGRANTFILE" was correctly pointing to a generated file, ".vagrant" dir was being generated inside my playbook directory (./provisioning).

After further research into [available environment variables](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/other/environmental-variables.html), I found a variable that was more useful; "VAGRANT_CWD".  This will locate the generated Vagrantfile as well as generate a correct ".vagrant" directory.  "vagrant status" now detects the running VMs correctly.

Here is what my code looks like now:

```
---
- block:
  - name: Copy vagrantfile onto dev machine
    local_action:
      template src=Vagrantfile.j2
      dest={{playbook_dir}}/../Vagrantfile

  - name: Boot up VMs
    local_action:
      command vagrant up
    environment:
      VAGRANT_CWD: "{{playbook_dir}}/.."
    register: vagrantUpResults

  - debug: msg="{{vagrantUpResults}}"

  tags:
  - vagrant
```